# Suggested Examples of Bayesian Hierarchical Modelling (using three levels) in WinBUGS/R

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-clustering, winbugs

I'm using WinBUGS/R to develop a Bayesian Hierarchical Model with three levels but I'm struggling to find decent examples of code. Can anyone suggest some please? I'm new to WinBUGS but not multilevel modelling and need help specifying the model in this language.

I have four repeated measure data points for local authority areas, nested within regions. Hence, I want to specify two random intercepts at the local authority and regional level.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I use Stan instead of BUGS and examples are found here: https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models/wiki

Answer (score 2):

I just coded an example in JAGS with simulated data.  BUGS code should be essentially identical.  The random effects ANOVA and Poisson GLMM in Marc Kery's [excellent book](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=introduction%20to%20winbugs%20for%20ecologists) include code that can easily be modified to include a second (hierarchical) random intercept.

```
library(rjags)

## DATA SIMULATION AND FORMATTING ##################################

n.regions <- 12
n.locations <- c(4,5,6,3,5,5,5,6,10,7,6,2)
n.reps <- 4

overall.mean <- 10
sigma.regions <- 2
sigma.locations <- 5
sigma.reps <- 1
n.obs <- sum(n.locations)*n.reps

region.means <- rnorm(12, 10, sigma.regions)
location.means <- vector()
for(i in 1:12){
  location.means <- c(location.means, rnorm(n.locations[i], region.means[i], sigma.locations))
}

my.data <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=n.obs, ncol=3))
names(my.data) = c("region", "location", "observed")
v <- vector()
for(i in 1:12){
  v <- c(v, rep(i, 4*n.locations[i]))
}
my.data$region <- v
my.data$location <- floor((0:(n.obs-1))/n.reps)+1
for(k in 1:n.obs){
  my.data$observed[k] <- rnorm(1, location.means[my.data$location[k]], sigma.reps)
}
locations.regions <- my.data[4*(1:64), ]

## JAGS CODE #################################################

sink("mymodel.txt")
cat("model{

    # Priors

    mu ~ dnorm(0, .001)
    ## Overall mean  

    sigma.regions ~ dunif(0,20)
    tau.regions <- 1/(sigma.regions*sigma.regions)
    sigma.locations ~ dunif(0,20)
    tau.locations <- 1/(sigma.locations*sigma.locations)
    sigma.reps ~ dunif(0,20)
    tau.reps <- 1/(sigma.reps*sigma.reps)


    # Model structure
    for(i in 1:n.regions){
    mu.region[i] ~ dnorm(mu, tau.regions)
    }
    for(i in 1:n.locations){
    mu.location[i] ~ dnorm(mu.region[region[i]], tau.locations)
    }
    for(i in 1:n.obs){
    observed[i] ~ dnorm(mu.location[location[i]], tau.reps)
    }
    }
    ", fill=TRUE)
sink()

## RJAGS CODE TO CALL JAGS AND RUN THE MODEL: ##################################

jags.data <- list(observed=my.data$observed, region=locations.regions$region, location=my.data$location, n.obs=n.obs, n.regions=12, n.locations=sum(n.locations))
inits <- function(){list(mu=rnorm(1,0,10), sigma.regions=runif(1,0,10),
                    sigma.locations=runif(1,0,10), sigma.reps=runif(1,0,10))}

params <- c("mu", "mu.region", "mu.location", "sigma.regions", "sigma.locations", "sigma.reps")

nc <- 5
n.adapt <-1000
n.burn <- 2000
n.iter <- 5000
thin <- 10
my.model <- jags.model('mymodel.txt', data = jags.data, inits=inits, n.chains=nc, n.adapt=n.adapt)
update(my.model, n.burn)
my.model_samples <- coda.samples(my.model,params,n.iter=n.iter, thin=thin)
summary(my.model_samples)
```